# how many nodes can a binary tree have at level n? Use induction to prove the answer

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, treenode

This is a homework and i didn't have much time to spent on it but I know some of the answer and need a little help plz

i'm thinking like this assume we have:

1 node  ----> Level 1

2,3 nodes ----> Level 2

3,4,5,6,7 nodes ----> level 3

4,5,6,.....,15 nodes ----> Level 4

5,6,7,8,9,.....,31 nodes ----> Level 5

node(s) interval from [ min=X node(s) TO max = 2^X - 1 node(s) ] where X represent the level

from now on i'm confused how to complete

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graph theory and math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall to use induction you have to prove the Nth case and the N + 1th case. And we see for any N that the N + 1th level has exactly twice as many. Thus shown by 2^(N + 1) / 2^N = 2

The total number of nodes can be found by taking the sum from n = 0 to N - 1 of 2^n

You probably want a more conclusive and verbose answer, but thats the gist.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have it right.
The minimum amount of nodes a binary tree can have is *n* and the maximum is *2^n-1*

Comment: What you've shown is proof by induction, you should formalize it a bit more, like in a statement.

Comment: if i wanna say at N+1 i have [N+1 to (2^(N+1)-1)] i got confused about the 2 values [N+1 to (2^(N+1)-1)] and how to prove the equality

Answer (score 0):

A node at level n in a binary tree will have n ancestors.
Proof by induction:
Show P(0): A node at level 0 has no ancestors. (This is true because it is the root.)
Show P(1): A node at level 1 has one ancestor. (This is true; the ancestor is the root, its father, which is at level 0.)
Assume P(K): A node at level K has K ancestors. Its father is at level K - 1.
Prove P(K+1): A node at level K+1 will have one more ancestor than the node at level K. The K+1th element will have a parent at level (K+1)-1, or level K.